# ReactJS - createReactClass - How to access component functions from outside?

Tags: reactjs

I successfully created a React component using `create-react-class` package and then I'm trying to access the component functions from outside it

```
import createReactClass from "create-react-class";

let Snackbar = createReactClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { status: "green" };
  },

  handleClick: function () {
    return "asd";
    // this.setState({ status: "red" });
  },

  render: function () {
    return <h1>{this.state.status}</h1>;
  }
});
```

Then I'm trying to render it to access the functions like this

```
var renderComponent = React.renderComponent(Snackbar);
renderComponent.handleClick();
```

This should work in React old versions but not in new versions

> I'm getting `renderComponent` is not a function

**is there any way to solve it to access the component functions?**

**What is the correct way to access the component functions from outside it?**

[image: Edit nifty-gauss-5lzc7]

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't work? What happens exactly when you run your code? And what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: what is your question?